# EF Core .Include() select latest item works wrong

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

My code:

```
var file = await this._dataContext.Files
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Include(x => x.FileVersions.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).Take(1))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var lastVersion = file.FileVersions.First();
```

I want to get `File` and its latest `FileVersion` only. But when I execute this code, I get the `File` and its first `FileVersion`.

Rewrote query to get SQL string:

```
var query = this._dataContext.Files
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Include(x => x.FileVersions.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).Take(1))
                .ToQueryString();
```

And result:

```
SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Archived], [f].[ContentType], [f].[CreatedByUserId], [f].[CreatedFromCustomFieldId], [f].[CreatedFromTemplateId], [f].[DateCreated], [f].[DateUpdated], [f].[Description], [f].[FileExtension], [f].[Filename], [f].[InternalType], [f].[Tags], [f].[Trashed], [f].[UpdatedByUserId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Comment], [t0].[CreatedByUserId], [t0].[DateCreated], [t0].[FileGUID], [t0].[FileHash], [t0].[FileId], [t0].[FileSizeBytes], [t0].[Infected], [t0].[Revision], [t0].[Scanned]
FROM [Files] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Comment], [t].[CreatedByUserId], [t].[DateCreated], [t].[FileGUID], [t].[FileHash], [t].[FileId], [t].[FileSizeBytes], [t].[Infected], [t].[Revision], [t].[Scanned]
    FROM (
        SELECT [f0].[Id], [f0].[Comment], [f0].[CreatedByUserId], [f0].[DateCreated], [f0].[FileGUID], [f0].[FileHash], [f0].[FileId], [f0].[FileSizeBytes], [f0].[Infected], [f0].[Revision], [f0].[Scanned], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [f0].[FileId] ORDER BY [f0].[Id] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [FileVersions] AS [f0]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [f].[Id] = [t0].[FileId]
WHERE [f].[Id] = @__id_0
ORDER BY [f].[Id], [t0].[FileId], [t0].[Id] DESC
```

Is it correct SQL?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong as far as I can tell. What EF Core version is this? Can we see the generated SQL? What type is the `Template` to `TemplateVersion` relationship, e.g. one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: EF Core v7, one to many relationship. How can I see generated SQL?

Comment: Was going to say `ToQueryString()`, but `FirstOrDefault` makes it impossible. Need to turn EF Core logging on, but that's not so easy to explain in comments. Anyway, tried your query with "classic" `Blog` -> `Posts` sample model, and it works as expected - returns blog with its latest post. So there must be something else with your environment/use case, which means we need [mre].

Comment: If you're only interested in `template.TemplateVersions.First()` you could (should) query `_dataContext.TemplateVersions` directly, but of course that only evades the issue. You could change `FirstOrDefaultAsync` into `Where` to be able to execute `template.ToQueryString()` (and return `(await template.FirstOrDefaultAsync()).First()`).

Comment: I would recommend just joining manually, using lazy or eager loading features is not good in my opinion because: it reduces code readability/maintainability and it is less reliable.

Comment: as for why it might not be working, perhaps the latest TemplateVersion could not join with Templates? do you have navigational properties properly set up?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy Thanks. Very strange, the SQL is what is should be (same as what I get, just different tables and columns of course). So everything looks good and should work. Last question before I give up - what is the type of PK / FK? Mine are `int`.

Comment: PK/FK have `int` type

Comment: Well, the query can't do anything but return the version with the highest Id. Since there's no room for magic, I can only conclude that you do get the correct data although maybe it's not what you expected somehow.